# Unable to install scikit-learn-intelex in Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I failed to install `scikit-learn-intelex` (ver. 2021.2.2) in Colab. Here was what I did in Colab:

```sh
! python -m pip install --upgrade pip
! python -m pip install scikit-learn-intelex
```

As a result, I got the following output, which looks normal to me.

```sh
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/cf/0cc542fc93de2f3b9b53cb979c7d1118cffb93204afb46299a9f858e113f/pip-21.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 11.3MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.3.1
Successfully installed pip-21.1
```

and

```sh
Collecting scikit-learn-intelex
  Downloading scikit_learn_intelex-2021.2.2-py37-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24 kB)
Collecting daal4py==2021.2.2
  Downloading daal4py-2021.2.2-py37-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.6 MB 108 kB/s 
Collecting dpcpp-cpp-rt==2021.*
  Downloading dpcpp_cpp_rt-2021.2.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (171.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 171.6 MB 80 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from daal4py==2021.2.2->scikit-learn-intelex) (1.19.5)
Collecting daal==2021.2.2
  Downloading daal-2021.2.2-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (295.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 295.7 MB 13 kB/s 
Collecting tbb==2021.*
  Downloading tbb-2021.2.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.9 MB 64.4 MB/s 
Collecting opencl-rt==2021.*
  Downloading opencl_rt-2021.2.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (169.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 169.0 MB 34 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: intel-openmp==2021.* in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dpcpp-cpp-rt==2021.*->daal4py==2021.2.2->scikit-learn-intelex) (2021.2.0)
Collecting common-cmplr-lib-rt==2021.*
  Downloading common_cmplr_lib_rt-2021.2.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (31.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 31.6 MB 162 kB/s 
Collecting common-cmplr-lic-rt==2021.*
  Downloading common_cmplr_lic_rt-2021.2.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24 kB)
Installing collected packages: tbb, common-cmplr-lic-rt, opencl-rt, common-cmplr-lib-rt, dpcpp-cpp-rt, daal, daal4py, scikit-learn-intelex
```

Then I restarted the kernel by clicking on `Restart runtime` in `Runtime` of the Colab window banner before running the following code:

```py
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
```

An error message was raised after running the code. It said:

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-45b0f2aba6d7> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearnex import patch_sklearn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearnex'


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone tell me how to install the package in Colab?

Comment: After the `Installing collected packages: tbb, common-cmplr-lic-rt ...`, did you get the `successfully installed ...` message for those packages, like you did for `pip` earlier?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, I got the same message as you, "`Successfully installed common-cmplr-lib-rt-2021.2.0 common-cmplr-lic-rt-2021.2.0 daal-2021.2.2 daal4py-2021.2.2 dpcpp-cpp-rt-2021.2.0 opencl-rt-2021.2.0 scikit-learn-intelex-2021.2.2 tbb-2021.2.0`."

Comment: I tried it and am getting the same error when trying to import.  The installation seems to work.  You can see that `pip` puts it in the same location as say `numpy` when you run `!pip show scikit-learn-intelex` in Colab.  Maybe open an issue on this package's Github.

Comment: @AlexK Just raise an issue on the package's Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround answered by the developer of the package on [GitHub](https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex/issues/634):

> Google colab is currently running on Debian system. One of the changes you may encounter on a Debian system is dist-packages instead of site-packages. Third party Python software installed from Debian packages goes into dist-packages, not site-packages.
> We are working on support for Debian systems and it should be fixed in the next release.
> For now, I can suggest the following workaround:

```
      import sys
      import os
      import site
      sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(site.getsitepackages()[0]), "site-packages"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem have been fixed with 2021.4 release. Thanks for reporting